# R/Rscript/Rio コマンドライン上でのパッケージインストールについて

Tags: r

『コマンドラインではじめるデータサイエンス』
https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117416/

の本のp127において

< data/iris.csv Rio -e 'skewness(df$sepal_length)'

とあります。skewnessはmoments パッケージに含まれてているのですが、

Rioで利用するためのインストール方法が本に記載がありません。
(インストールしておく必要があります。という記述だけ)
インストール方法がご存知の方がいらっしゃりましたら、ご教授願います

Comment: 参考になるかもしれないです http://qiita.com/gingi99/items/01d1d792f50e2b45fac3

Comment: R で `install.packages("moments");` を実行します(パッケージをインストールするのと同じ方法)。ただ、これだけでは動作しませんので、Rio スクリプトの `REQUIRES=` の部分に `moments` パッケージをロードする処理を追加する必要があります。`REQUIRES='require(moments);'`

Comment: metropolisさんありがとうございます。 < iris.csv   Rio -e 'REQUIRES=require(moments);skewness(df$sepal_length)' で動きました！！！ただ、本では、< iris.csv   Rio -e  'skewness(df$sepal_length)' だけで動いています。毎回毎回、require()しなくても済む方法をご存知でしたらご教授ねがいます

Comment: Rio のスクリプトファイルを編集するのはどうでしょう。56行目にある `REQUIRES=` の部分がそうです。`REQUIRES='require(moments, quietly=T);'` としておくとロードメッセージが表示されないので良いかもしれません。